# Solidworks VBA, Sheet Metal Part swmodel.visible = false not working

Tags: vba, solidworks, solidworksapi

I have a function in my macro that is saving all parts from an assembly into .dxf format.  this function sorts through all of the parts in the assembly to only process the parts with "PL" in the custom properties.  In this PL category, there are two types of parts.  sheet metal parts and regular "plate" parts. I am able to make all parts visible when they need to be but only regular parts will become invisible.  I do not understand why the sheet metal parts are the only exception.

```
Function PrintDXF(ByRef swPrtDoc As ModelDoc2) As String

Dim sa As Variant
Dim swBody As SldWorks.Body2
Dim i As Integer
Dim modelPath As String
Dim OUT_PATH As String
Dim swSelObj As Object
Dim smExpRetVal As Boolean
Dim prtExpRetVal As Boolean
Dim fso1 As New FileSystemObject

If swPrtDoc.GetType = swDocPART Then

    Set swPart = swPrtDoc
    modelPath = swPart.GetPathName
        
    prtCustProp
       
    OUT_PATH = savePath & "\" & CustPropPiece & ".dxf"
    Debug.Print OUT_PATH
    If Not fso1.FileExists(OUT_PATH) Then
     
     If CustPropType = "PL" Then
        
        swPrtDoc.Visible = True
        sa = swPart.GetBodies2(swSolidBody, True)
        
            For i = 0 To UBound(sa)
            Set swBody = sa(i)
                If swBody.IsSheetMetal Then
                    smExpRetVal = swPart.ExportToDWG2(OUT_PATH, modelPath, swExportToDWG_e.swExportToDWG_ExportSheetMetal, True, Empty, False, False, SheetMetalOptions_e.ExportFlatPatternGeometry + SheetMetalOptions_e.ExportBendLines, Empty)
                
                    If smExpRetVal = False Then
                        err.Raise vbError, "", "Failed to export sheet metal part"
                    Else
                        swPrtDoc.Visible = False
                    End If
                Else
                    Set swSelMgr = swPrtDoc.SelectionManager
                        While swSelObj Is Nothing
                            Dim y As Integer
            
                            For y = 1 To swSelMgr.GetSelectedObjectCount2(-1)
                                If swSelMgr.GetSelectedObjectType3(y, -1) = FilterY Then
                                    Set swSelObj = swSelMgr.GetSelectedObject6(1, -1)
                                End If
                            Next
                            DoEvents
                        Wend
                    
                   prtExpRetVal = swPart.ExportToDWG2(OUT_PATH, modelPath, swExportToDWG_ExportSelectedFacesOrLoops, True, Empty, False, False, Empty, Null)
                        If prtExpRetVal = False Then
                            err.Raise vbError, "", "Failed to export part"
                        Else
                            
                        End If
                    swPrtDoc.ClearSelection2 True
                End If
                swPrtDoc.Visible = False
            Next
            AcadApp.Visible = True
            AcadApp.Documents.Open OUT_PATH
            AcadApp.ActiveDocument.SendCommand ("QWB") & vbCr
            AcadApp.Visible = False
            'killPath = Replace(OUT_PATH, "dxf", "bak")
            'Debug.Print killPath
            'Kill killPath
    End If
End If
End If
End Function
```

I tried to move `swPrtDoc.Visible = False` to different lines to see if that made any difference- it did not.
i tried to close the document using `swApp.CloseDoc ""` - it did not close the sheet metal document

Comment: Hey, in this line `sa = swPart.GetBodies2(swSolidBody, True)` you are only asking for solid bodies to be saved to sa. You should try with swAllBodies to obtain both solid and sheet bodies. See documentation on swBodyType_e Enumeration